# Understanding the linkerscript for an ARM Cortex-M microcontroller

Tags: linker, arm, cortex-m, linker-scripts, newlib

I am using the STM32F746NG microcontroller from STMicroelectronics. This device is based on the ARM Cortex-M7 architecture. I invested quite some time in understanding the linkerscript from example projects. I figured out the basics, but I still cannot grasp big parts of it. Please help me to understand those parts.

#### Start of the linkerscript

The linkerscript starts as follows:

```
/* Entry Point */
ENTRY(Reset_Handler) /* The function named 'Reset_Handler' is defined */
                     /* in the 'startup.s' assembly file.             */

/* Highest address of the user mode stack */
/* Remember: the stack points downwards */
_estack = 0x20050000;    /* End of RAM */

/* Generate a link error if heap and stack don't fit into RAM */
_Min_Heap_Size = 0x200;  /* Required amount of heap  */
_Min_Stack_Size = 0x400; /* Required amount of stack */

/* --------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*                    MEMORY AREAS                                     */
/* --------------------------------------------------------------------*/
MEMORY
{
    /* FLASH MEMORY */
    /* ------------ */
    /* Remember: the flash memory on this device can   */
    /* get accessed through either the AXIM bus or the */
    /* ITCM bus. Accesses on the ITCM bus start at     */
    /* address 0x0020 0000. Accesses on the AXIM bus   */
    /* at address 0x0800 0000.                         */
    FLASH (rx)     : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 1024K
    /* FLASH (rx)     : ORIGIN = 0x00200000, LENGTH = 1024K */

    /* RAM MEMORY */
    /* ---------- */
    RAM (xrw)      : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 320K
}
```

#### Vector table and program code

After defining the memory areas, the linkerscript proceeds with defining the sections. The first section defined in the linkerscript is the vector table. It has to end up in the first bytes of the flash memory.

```
/* --------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*                    OUTPUT SECTIONS                                  */
/* --------------------------------------------------------------------*/
SECTIONS
{
    /****************************/
    /*      VECTOR TABLE        */
    /****************************/
    .isr_vector :
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        KEEP(*(.isr_vector)) /* Vector Table */
        . = ALIGN(4);
    } >FLASH
```

After the vector table is inserted, it's time for the program code:

```
    /****************************/
    /*      PROGRAM CODE        */
    /****************************/
    .text :
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        *(.text)           /* .text sections (code) */
        *(.text*)          /* .text* sections (code) */
        *(.glue_7)         /* Glue ARM to Thumb code */
        *(.glue_7t)        /* Glue Thumb to ARM code */
        *(.eh_frame)


        /* Note: The function ‘.text.Reset_Handler’ is one of the *(.text*) sections,      */
        /* such that it gets linked into the output .text section somewhere here.          */
        /* We can verify the exact spot where the Reset_Handler section is positioned, by  */
        /* examining the second entry of the vector table.                                 */
        /* A test has given the following results:
        /*    FLASH (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x0800 0000    ==>  Reset_Handler = 0x0800 1C91        */
        /*    FLASH (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x0020 0000    ==>  Reset_Handler = 0x0020 1CB9        */
        /*
        /* In both cases, the Reset_Handler section ends up a few hundred bytes after the  */
        /* vector table in Flash. But in the first case, the “Reset_Handler” symbol points */
        /* to the Reset-code through AXIM-interface, whereas in the latter case it points  */
        /* to the Reset-code through the ITCM-interface.                                   */


        KEEP (*(.init))
        KEEP (*(.fini))

        . = ALIGN(4);
        _etext = .;        /* Define a global symbol at end of code */

    } >FLASH
```

The linkerscript defines the `e_text` global symbol that represents the address where the program code in flash ends.

#### Constant data

The read-only data ends up in the flash memory as well (it makes no sense to put it in RAM, which is volatile). The linkerscript defines that the `.rodata` section should be in flash:

```
    /****************************/
    /*      CONSTANT DATA       */
    /****************************/
    .rodata :
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        *(.rodata)         /* .rodata sections (constants, strings, etc.) */
        *(.rodata*)        /* .rodata* sections (constants, strings, etc.) */
        . = ALIGN(4);
    } >FLASH
```

#### Mysterious sections in flash

After defining where the constant read-only data should go, the linkerscript defines that a few 'mysterious' sections should end up in flash as well:

```
    .ARM.extab :
    {
        *(.ARM.extab* .gnu.linkonce.armextab.*)
    } >FLASH
    .ARM :
    {
        __exidx_start = .;
        *(.ARM.exidx*)
        __exidx_end = .;
    } >FLASH
    .preinit_array :
    {
        PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_start = .);
        KEEP (*(.preinit_array*))
        PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_end = .);
    } >FLASH
    .init_array :
    {
        PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_start = .);
        KEEP (*(SORT(.init_array.*)))
        KEEP (*(.init_array*))
        PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_end = .);
    } >FLASH
    .fini_array :
    {
        PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_start = .);
        KEEP (*(SORT(.fini_array.*)))
        KEEP (*(.fini_array*))
        PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_end = .);
    } >FLASH
```

I have no idea what those sections are. So let this be the first question. What are these sections, and in what object files do they show up? As you know, the linkerscript needs to link together some object files. I have no idea in what object files these mysterious sections exist:

- `.ARM.extab`
- `.ARM`
- `.preinit_array`
- `.init_array`
- `.fini_array`

This is the end of allocations to the flash memory. The linkerscript continues with defining sections that end up in the RAM.

#### Sections in RAM

The `.data` and `.bss` sections are clear to me. No questions about this.

```
    /****************************/
    /*    INITIALIZED DATA      */
    /****************************/
    _sidata = LOADADDR(.data);
    .data :
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _sdata = .;        /* create a global symbol at data start */
        *(.data)           /* .data sections */
        *(.data*)          /* .data* sections */

        . = ALIGN(4);
        _edata = .;        /* define a global symbol at data end */

    } >RAM AT> FLASH


    /****************************/
    /*    UNINITIALIZED DATA    */
    /****************************/
    . = ALIGN(4);
    .bss :
    {
        _sbss = .;         /* define a global symbol at bss start */
        __bss_start__ = _sbss;
        *(.bss)
        *(.bss*)
        *(COMMON)

        . = ALIGN(4);
        _ebss = .;         /* define a global symbol at bss end */
        __bss_end__ = _ebss;

    } >RAM
```

The linkerscript defines also a `._user_heap_stack` section:

```
    /****************************/
    /* USER_HEAP_STACK SECTION  */
    /****************************/
    /* User_heap_stack section, used to check that there is enough RAM left */
    ._user_heap_stack :
    {
        . = ALIGN(8);
        PROVIDE ( end = . );
        PROVIDE ( _end = . );
        . = . + _Min_Heap_Size;
        . = . + _Min_Stack_Size;
        . = ALIGN(8);
    } >RAM
```

Apparently this section is not used immediately. It is only defined to check if the RAM has still enough space for the stack and the heap. A linker error is thrown when this is not the case (the `.` exceeds the top RAM address).

#### The end of the linkerscript

This is how the linkerscript ends. And honestly, I have no idea what it does. So this is the second question: What does the following mean?

```
    /* Remove information from the standard libraries */
    /DISCARD/ :
    {
        libc.a ( * )
        libm.a ( * )
        libgcc.a ( * )
    }

    .ARM.attributes 0 : { *(.ARM.attributes) }
}
/* END OF LINKERSCRIPT */
```

Comment: The `ARM.attributes` seems to be for some metadata about the target CPU https://github.com/ARM-software/abi-aa/blob/main/aaelf32/aaelf32.rst#build-attributes

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. .ARM.extab and .ARM.exidx are related to unwinding. You can find more information here http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0044e/index.html. You don't need them if you don't care about unwinding (unwinding is useful for C++ exception and for debugging).
2. These symbols are related to the C / C++ constructor and destructor startup and tear down code that is called before / after main(). Sections named .init, .ctors, .preinit_array, and .init_array are to do with initialization of C/C++ objects, and sections .fini, .fini_array, and .dtors are for tear down. The start and end symbols define the beginning and end of code sections related to such operations and might be referenced from other parts of the runtime support code.

The .preinit_array and .init_array sections contain arrays of pointers to functions that will be called on initialization. The .fini_array is an array of functions that will be called on destruction. Presumably the start and end labels are used to walk these lists.

3. heap: not really, that part permits to reserve some space for the heap and some space for the stack. Obviously it rises an error if the sum of reserved areas goes outside the RAM boundaries. This is an example:

   _Min_Heap_Size = 0;      /* required amount of heap  */
   _Min_Stack_Size = 0x400; /* required amount of stack */

   ._user_heap_stack :
   {
     . = ALIGN(4);
     PROVIDE ( end = . );
     PROVIDE ( _end = . );
     . = . + _Min_Heap_Size;
     . = . + _Min_Stack_Size;
     . = ALIGN(4);
   } >RAM
4. to link libraries I prefer a different notation, this is  just an example for a bare-metal no RTOS C++ project:
   GROUP(libgcc.a libc_nano.a libstdc++_nano.a libm.a libcr_newlib_nohost.a crti.o crtn.o crtbegin.o crtend.o)

Comment: Thank you sir. Your answers are really helpful! :-)

Comment: @massimo You should add this: One interesting detail that wasn't mentioned:
`.data : 
{
. = ALIGN(4);
_sdata = .; /* create a global symbol at data start */
*(.data) /* .data sections */
*(.data*) /* .data* sections */

. = ALIGN(4);
_edata = .; /* define a global symbol at data end */

} >RAM AT> FLASH 
`
The data section is put into flash. Why is that interesting? Because the .data sections are read/write. They're put into flash so that they are there when the power is turned on. The startup code copies them to RAM. Unfortunately I can't figure out how to add line breaks.

Comment: The answer seems to provide good information, however, I find that it is complex and very interleaved. May I ask you to reformat it and try to regroup the information? or could the asker (@K.Mulier) do this if he got a good understanding after this question? The second question (about the last part of linker script) is still not answered.

Answer (score -3):

First of all, your approach to understanding this concept is wrong; that is what I believe. I had faced a similar problem during the understanding of this concept.

In simple language, I can explain you that the linker script provides us three major things:

1. Entry point
2. Run-time addresses in main memory.
3. Copy down procedure

---

So let’s consider one example,

Assume that we have N number of .c files in our project. Now after compilation each file contains its own translation units called the object files.

Each object file contains the `.text` section/segment which contain the actual code. And .data section/segment for data.

To combine all `.text` section of each translation unit the linker script provides some specific commands for the same. This is the same for the `.data` section as well.

### After combining all the object files the final executable is ready to use.

Now coming to the some paradox...

The entry point in case of the Cortex-M series is just the ResetISR.
After executing the ResetISR function and initialize the other maskable interrupts in SoC, the next step is the copy-down procedure.

The copy-down procedure is nothing but to copy the `.data` section into RAM (which includes the interesting `.bss` section even, but I am not considering that part right now).

Copy from ROM to RAM is essential, because the actual ELF file is always stored in the ROM.

After performing all these startup-related things, we can now call our `main()` function.

Comment: This answer has practically nothing to do with the question. It talks (poorly, I might add) about a linker script from a very high level, which the OP clearly already understands quite well.